# Como hacer backup de SqlServer desde C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Hola buenas estoy creando una pantalla para crear un respaldo de mi base de datos, pero me da error de acceso
el codigo es el siguiente:

```
private void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nombre ;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRuta.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe Seleccionar una ruta y nombre de archivo.");
        }
        else
        {
            nombre = txtRuta.Text;
            SqlCommand commando;
            commando = new SqlCommand(@"backup database prueba to disk ='"+nombre+".bak' with init,stats=10", Conexion);
            try
            {
                Conexion.Open();
                commando.ExecuteNonQuery();                  
                MessageBox.Show("El backup se ha generado con exito.");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show("Hubo un Error queriendo generar el backup"+ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Conexion.Close();
                Conexion.Dispose();
            }
        
        }
    }

    private void btnRuta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                string str_RutaArchivo = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                txtRuta.Text = str_RutaArchivo;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

este es el error que me muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en sqlserver obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar que ese codigo en el sqlcommand lo saque de aca de esta plataforma,
no se que puede estar pasando? alguna idea? de antemano gracias.

Comment: Tu programa y tu base de datos están en el mismo servidor?

Comment: si es correcto, con la diferencia que en vez de el nombre de el sevidor le paso la ip de la maquina, igual al momento de ingresar a sql server, ingreso con el usuario SA y en nombre de servidor pongo la ip de la maquina, hasta ahora llevo meses asi y sin problema

Comment: entonces ahí el problema que el usuario de el SQL server no tiene acceso a tu carpeta, tienes que darle acceso a esa carpeta o carpetas, ya que esta intentando acceder a la carpeta de tu usuario, o genera tu respaldo en otra donde si tenga acceso o todos los usuarios tengan acceso.

Comment: Parece un problema de permisos en el sistema de archivos. Revisa que la cuenta de servicio de SQL Server tenga acceso a esa ruta.

Comment: alguien sabe como le doy permiso a un usuario de sql acceso a las carpetas de la maquina? osea que pasaria si yo tuviera la base en la nube? como seria en ese caso? porque el backup lo quiero en maquina, para que el usuario por ejemplo pueda generar un backup semanal y no pierda todos los datos

Comment: El backup tiene que ir a una ruta, donde el servicio de sql tenga acceso siempre, si es ruta local o ruta por carpeta compartida, pero debe estar mapeada en el servidor.

Comment: intentare darle permisos de la forma clasica a ver que sale o que dice diosito

Comment: ya lo logre, segui este link, y asi logre hacerlo en un carpeta con los permisos definidos para esa carpeta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286765/sql-server-operating-system-error-5-5access-is-denied

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda